Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unauthenticated" exception
I create a simple c# app to query data in Firestore. The code is as follows:
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"data\firebase.json";
FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create("aestest-3e45c");
CollectionReference  usersRef = db.Collection("users");

Google.Cloud.Firestore.DocumentReference userRef = usersRef.Document(uuid);
Dictionary<string, object> updates = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
     { "uuid", uuid }
};
 await userRef.UpdateAsync(updates);

.......
I install the c# app in five computers that run in the same network. Four of them run without any error but one receive the error message:
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unauthenticated", Detail="Request had invalid authentication credentials.
Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."
I reinsall windows 10 on that computer and try, but I get the same error too!
Any advice is appreciated
Thank you very much.

How are you authenticating your app? Your code sample assumes (correctly!) the use of Application Default Credentials but your question does not include details of how you're providing these credentials your code (e.g. Service Account). Where are you running the app? What's different about the 5th machine (evidently something; probably that it's not using ADC correctly).

Hello DazWikin, I download the Service account private key and save it as the firebase.json file which contains all information for the Service Account.I run tha app in local computer and directly query to firebase and all computers running windows 10.

The variable path created by string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"data\firebase.json"; appears to not be used by your code. I wonder whether, by reinstalling, you've deleted your user credentials stored as Application Default Credentials. Check a working machine and then your machine for (Windows) %APPDATA%\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json (see user credentials provided by Cloud CLI)

If the file exists on the working machines, then you could gcloud application-default login to reproduce the credentials on the non-working machine. These should be found automatically by ADC and used by the client library in your code.

Hello DazWilkin, Thank you so much. I will try it and tell you if the method works.

Hello DazWilkin, still not working. It is really weird.
